# Vuejs nginx dockerised app not working with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js, docker-compose

I have a production stage dockerised vuejs front end app served with nginx server.

When I run the single container using the command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 my-dockerhub-username/my-vuejs-app
```

then it runc fine and I can reach it on port 80.

...however, for some reason when I use docker-compose to spin up my app using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    api:
      image: my-dockerhub-username/my-vuejs-app
      ports:
        - 80:80
    web:
      image: my-dockerhub-username/my-rest-api
      ports:
        - 9001:9001
```

I cannot reach my app on port 80.

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

I would appreciate any sugestions anybody can offer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your service names are reversed, is that the issue? Your question lacks any detail on what the issue is.

Comment: besides the names of the services being inverted, are your containers running after a `docker-compose up`? You can check with `docker-compose ps`